# (WP) Hide Admin Menu & Restricted Access Based On User Role

Tags: wordpress

I want to hide admin menu and restricted access on that page for Wordpress. For hide administration menu, I've done it. Here is example code:

```
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_remove_menu_pages' );

function my_remove_menu_pages() {
    // If the user does not have access to publish posts
    if(!current_user_can('manage_options')) {
        remove_menu_page('tools.php');
    }
}
```

I'm create new user role, for example is image_uploader. How can I do to restricted access on page that related to admin menu that I've hide based on user role? At now, it's just hide admin menu and not restricted, that mean, user who keep link will get access of that page. And this code not specific to user role, but specific to user capabilities.

What I want is hide and restricted menu and page based on specific user role. How can I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the hook [**`load-$page`**](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/load-%28page%29), like:

```
# /wp-admin/$page.php
$pages = array( 'profile', 'tools' );

foreach( $pages as $page )
    add_action( "load-$page.php", 'block_user_so_23568456' );

function block_user_so_23568456()
{
    $user = get_userdata( get_current_user_id() );

    # Send this user role to the Dashboard /wp-admin/index.php
    if ( in_array( 'image_uploader', $user->roles ) ) 
    {
        wp_redirect( admin_url() );
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: How can I block for custom board page? Example: /wp-admin/admin.php?page=my-custom-dashboard

Comment: Hi, Yiedpozi, yes, it's possible, add `'admin'` to the $pages  array, then use `global $pagenow;` to detect `admin.php` and finally `isset( $_GET['page'] )` to confirm it's your page. If you can't solve, ping me again here, I'm not on the computer and cannot test, but that's the blueprint :)