# Disable "Add User" functionality from backend in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

How can I disable creating user from backend. I want all the users to be registered from front end registration form (I am using Pie Register Plugin for registration), There should not be an option to "Add User" in wp-admin area even for admin.

How do I do that?  some custom code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `functions.php` add the following:

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_menus');
function remove_menus()
{
    global $submenu;
    remove_submenu_page ('users.php', 'user-new.php');    //Dashboard->Updates
}
```

Comment: The `global` is not needed here. Check [the following](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23570538/1287812) to redirect access to `/wp-admin/user-new.php`.

Comment: He wants to disable creating user from backend even for admin!!

Answer (score 1):

Removing the submenu page is a good approach. However, you can still type the URL (e.g. https://example.com/wordpress/wp-admin/new-user.php) and that will take you to the page you are trying to hide. Consider:

```
add_action('admin_menu', function () {
    remove_submenu_page ('users.php', 'users.php');  // disable listing users
    remove_submenu_page ('users.php', 'user-new.php');  // disable adding new users
    remove_submenu_page ('users.php', 'user-edit.php'); // disable editing other users

    if(
        preg_match('/users\.php/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || 
        preg_match('/user-new\.php/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']) || 
        preg_match('/user-edit\.php/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])
    ) {
        // redirect to another page (e.g. homepage)
        header("Location: " . home_url());
        exit;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to remove the capability to create new users. For more information read this [documentation](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/).

```
add_action('init', 'remove_create_users_capability');
function remove_create_users_capability(){
    $role = get_role('administrator');
    $role->remove_cap('create_users');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It prevents of registering users over admin area, REST and xml rpc

```
function execute_on_register_post_event($sanitized_user_login, $user_email, $errors){
    wp_die('Forbidden, manualy disabled');
}
add_action( "register_post", "execute_on_register_post_event" , 10, 3);

add_filter( 'pre_user_login' , 'my_username_block' );
function my_username_block( $user_login ) {
    wp_die('Forbidden, manualy disabled');
}
```